# How does python use paths when a script is called using eval() from a php script and when the same function is called from a bash script?

Tags: python, php, linux, bash

I have an executable python script which archives data from mysql server using the pymysql library.  The script works well from the command line.

I call this script from a php script using escapeshellcmd function and I've gotten it to work.

I also have created a bash script that I intend to use from crontab to archive the information as well. I can make this script work as well, by making changes outlined below.

Somehow I have gotten into python versions and path problems.

if I include

```
#!/home/tim/anaconda3/bin/python
```

as the first line of the python script it works when called by the php script (using www-data as the user, I believe).  It doesn't work from the bash script or the command line, giving the following error:

```
  File "./signal_archive.py", line 22, in <module>
    import pymysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

However, if the first line of the python script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

the script works from the bash script and the command line but not from the php script.  It gives the following error:

```
  File "/home/tim/python/commodities_related/signal_archive.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Both packages are installed on my system.  Thinking pointing the script to the path would help, I added the following to the python script but no luck so far.

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages:')
```

There is obviously something I'm missing;  I think it is that php script is called by www-user and I don't know the default path.  The bash file is called by my user with the path specified in the .bashrc file.  However, I may need to point the apache or php (www-user) to use a specific installation of python.

EDIT-
To be more clear, a php script (phpfile1.php) calls the python script.  When I call phpfile1.php from another php script (phpfile2.php) running on apache2 I everything works using the

```
#!/home/tim/anaconda3/bin/python
```

When I call the same file (phpfile1.php) from a different php script (phpfile3.php) from a bash script it fails.
Additionally, if I run the file in place using the following

```
./signal_archive.py
```

I get the error but if I run it using the following command it works:

```
python signal_archive.py
```

Any ideas if this is right or how to do it?  Thanks.

Comment: You may try this , keep the line [/home/tim/anaconda3/bin/python ] which works with php and while calling the script from your bash script use the same python path and call the script.  /home/tim/anaconda3/bin/python <your script >. Worth a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in 2 steps:

It turns out that I needed to add the path to anaconda3 to my .bash_profile file.

```
export PATH="/home/tim/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

When anaconda3 is installed it modifies the .bashrc file with the previous code snippet.  However .bash_profile made the difference in this case.

I also modified the top of the python file to use the anaconda path for execution, as well as add the path for the specific python packages.

```
#!/home/tim/anaconda3/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages')
```